# Open Rotativa print dialog automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I am using Rotativa to generate a PDF of a view with the intention of printing it.

I have the following code

```
public ActionResult PrintTicket(string tempTickID)
{
   //var tick = ctx.vw_printTicket.Where(e => e.noTicket == tempTickID).FirstOrDefault();
   // return View(tick);

    var report = new ActionAsPdf("PrepareTicket", new { tempTickID = tempTickID });
    return report;
}
```

ActionAsPdf allows me to open the "PrepareTicket" view as a pdf and then I can print.

**Problem**

The problem for me is this, The pdf takes over my entire page and while I can print I don't have access to my program's menus anymore cause it's now a PDF view.

**Questions**

Is it possible that I call the print dialog automatically instead of showing the pdf?

I think will work for my situation.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have tried to create a sample which will solve your issue.

> 1. Model

```
public class Ticketinfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

> 2. Created a Controller which has 3 Action Method

```
public class GenerateController : Controller
{

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PrintTicket(string tempTickID)
        {
            return new ActionAsPdf("RotativaPartialViewAsPdf", new { tempTickID = tempTickID });
        }

        public ActionResult RotativaPartialViewAsPdf(string tempTickID)
        {
            Ticketinfo Ticketinfo = new Ticketinfo()
            {
                name =  "Demo",
                quantity = 5
            };

            return PartialView("_RotativaPartialViewAsPdfl", Ticketinfo);
        }

}
```

> 3. Partial View

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.Ticketinfo
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <tr class="info">
                <td>Lot</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="success">
                <td>@Model.name</td>
                <td>@Model.quantity</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> 4. Index View

```html
 @{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="@Url.Action("PrintTicket", "Generate", new {tempTickID = "1"})" 
                width="800px" height="600px">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Output

[image: Output]